# Return complex nested document from elasticsearch aggregation

Tags: typescript, elasticsearch, search, aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a document that looks like this:

```
{
...other stuff
"tags": [
          {
            "name": "Asian",
            "key": "cuisine-asian"
          },
          {
            "name": "Gluten Free",
            "key": "cuisine-gluten-free"
          }
```

My index mapping looks like this:

```
tags: {
  type: 'nested',
  properties: {
    name: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    key: {
      type: 'keyword',
  }
}
```

The `key` field is guaranteed to be unique.

I am trying to return a list of all "tags" in their complete form.
My current query can return a list of buckets with the key field, but I can't figure out how to return the entire "tag" object.

Query:

```
{
  ...
  body: {
    size: 0,
    aggs: {
      tags: {
        nested: {
          path: 'tags'
        },
        aggs: {
          tag_list: {
            terms: {
              size: 999,
              field: 'tags.key',
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which generates the response:

```
   "aggregations": {
      "tags": {
        "doc_count": 1708,
        "tag_list": {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key": "cuisine-asian",
              "doc_count": 247
            },
            {
              "key": "cuisine-drinks",
              "doc_count": 112
            },
```

I am hoping to get something that looks more like the following:

```
"buckets": [
            {
              "key": "cuisine-asian",
              "name": "Asian",
              "doc_count": 247
            },
            {
              "key": "cuisine-drinks",
              "name": "Drinks",
              "doc_count": 112
            },
```

If it matters/helps, the `doc_count` field is irrelevant - I only care about a list of cardinal values of the form

```
            {
              "key": "cuisine-drinks",
              "name": "Drinks",
            },
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) to create buckets on combine value of tag_key and tag_name.

In composite aggregation  [after_key](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_pagination) is used for pagination

**Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "tag": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "tags"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "tag_list": {
          "composite": {
            "sources": [
              {
                "tags_key": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "tags.key"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "tags_name": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "tags.name.keyword"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "tag" : {
      "doc_count" : 2,
      "tag_list" : {
        "after_key" : {
          "tags_key" : "cuisine-gluten-free",
          "tags_name" : "Gluten Free"
        },
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : {
              "tags_key" : "cuisine-asian",
              "tags_name" : "Asian"
            },
            "doc_count" : 1
          },
          {
            "key" : {
              "tags_key" : "cuisine-gluten-free",
              "tags_name" : "Gluten Free"
            },
            "doc_count" : 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Or you can use [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation to get full document under a key.
**Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "tags": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "tags"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "tag_list": {
          "terms": {
            "size": 999,
            "field": "tags.key"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "docs": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "tags" : {
      "doc_count" : 2,
      "tag_list" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "cuisine-asian",
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "docs" : {
              "hits" : {
                "total" : {
                  "value" : 1,
                  "relation" : "eq"
                },
                "max_score" : 1.0,
                "hits" : [
                  {
                    "_index" : "index26",
                    "_type" : "_doc",
                    "_id" : "yMDvAXIB90IHVdbFflZp",
                    "_nested" : {
                      "field" : "tags",
                      "offset" : 0
                    },
                    "_score" : 1.0,
                    "_source" : {
                      "name" : "Asian",
                      "key" : "cuisine-asian"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "cuisine-gluten-free",
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "docs" : {
              "hits" : {
                "total" : {
                  "value" : 1,
                  "relation" : "eq"
                },
                "max_score" : 1.0,
                "hits" : [
                  {
                    "_index" : "index26",
                    "_type" : "_doc",
                    "_id" : "yMDvAXIB90IHVdbFflZp",
                    "_nested" : {
                      "field" : "tags",
                      "offset" : 1
                    },
                    "_score" : 1.0,
                    "_source" : {
                      "name" : "Gluten Free",
                      "key" : "cuisine-gluten-free"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @JamieStrauss Glad could be of help :)

Comment: We'd like to reward this as a bounty considering the amount of time we burned trying to get this to work, if you're interested in receiving it email me at jamie@liven.com.au jaspreet.   Cheers.